# Pointer to element in struct array

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am adapting this C version of quicksort (https://www.programiz.com/dsa/quick-sort) to use the arb_t data type (https://arblib.org/arb.html#c.arb_struct) from arblib. I got one pointer problem left that I cannot solve. It's the swap function, where I need a pointer to an element in the arb_t struct. Other than that it should just swap the values and arb_t values can be set with arb_set.

```
void swap(arb_t *a, arb_t *b) {
  arb_t t;
  arb_init(t);
  arb_set(t, *a);
  arb_set(*a,*b);
  arb_set(*b,t);
}

// function to find the partition position
int partition(arb_t array, int low, int high) {
  
  // select the rightmost element as pivot
  arb_t pivot;
  arb_init(pivot);
  arb_set(&array[high], pivot);
  
  // pointer for greater element
  int i = (low - 1);

  // traverse each element of the array
  // compare them with the pivot
  for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
    if (arb_le (&array[j],pivot) == 1) {
        
      // if element smaller than pivot is found
      // swap it with the greater element pointed by i
      i++;
      
      // swap element at i with element at j
      swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
    }
  }

  // swap the pivot element with the greater element at i
  swap(&array[i + 1], &array[high]);
  
  // return the partition point
  return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(arb_ptr array, int low, int high) {
  if (low < high) {
    
    // find the pivot element such that
    // elements smaller than pivot are on left of pivot
    // elements greater than pivot are on right of pivot
    int pi = partition(array, low, high);
    
    // recursive call on the left of pivot
    quickSort(array, low, pi - 1);
    
    // recursive call on the right of pivot
    quickSort(array, pi + 1, high);
  }
}

// function to print array elements
void printArray(arb_ptr array
, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    arb_printd(&array[i],6);
    printf("\n");
  }
  
}

// main function
int main() {
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  int n = 5;
  arb_ptr data = _arb_vec_init(n);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      arb_t rnd;
      arb_init(rnd);
      arb_set_d(rnd, (double)(rand()%100)/10);
      arb_set(&data[i], rnd);
  }
  
  printf("Unsorted Array\n");
  printArray(data, n);
  
   //perform quicksort on data
//  quickSort(data, 0, n - 1);
//  
//  printf("Sorted array in ascending order: \n");
//  printArray(data, n);
}
```

I changed the array type to arb_ptr, which is the arb_t array type. Also I put in arb_le which is `x <= y` for arb_t. But in the swap, I get this pointer warning:

```
expected 'arb_struct (*)[1]' {aka 'struct <anonymous> (*)[1]'} but argument is of type 'arb_struct *' {aka 'struct <anonymous> *'}
    9 | void swap(arb_t *a, arb_t *b) {
```

How can I fix the pointer type? I tried various work arounds, but it's definitely the pointer type.

Comment: Kindly include all relevant information in your question.

Comment: What is an arb_t? (Not as external link, but in the question). 
If the question is about swapping, it should be possible to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest complete code that shows the problem (that does not involve sorting). By constructing that MRE, you might discover the problem yourself.